# How to calculate the distance between two x and y points?

Tags: coordinates

The euclidean formula $\sqrt{{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}}$ works just fine when $ x{_1} = x{_2} \vee y{_1} = y{_2}$ but when calculating diagonals where $ x{_1} \neq x{_2} \wedge y{_1} \neq y{_2} $ things get a bit odd for my needs because it returns even values.

What I really need is to calculate the difference between two points but didn't find anything about it, for example:

From value $ 8 $ where $x=0 \wedge y=0 $ to center point $ 0 $ where $ x=4 \wedge y=4 $ I would like the result to be $ 4 $.

[image: Matrix]

I could divide the result to get what I need but then the other values will be messed up, is there any formula that calculates the difference between two points?

Edit:
I will add more details to my question.

Given this matrix of 8x8 squares, suppose that from the given origin (4,4) I have a Cartesian plane where the rows are represented by **Y axis** and columns by **X axis**:

[image: Cartesian plane]

---

Extending arrows from the origin until the edges I have the positions where I need to perform the calculations

[image: straight lines from origin]

---

As said before, using the euclidean formula I can find the amount of square from the origin to the desired position but only for X and Y axes.

For instance, the amount of square from origin(4,4) to position(4,1) = 3 squares

[image: First example]

---

Another example, from origin(4,4) to (2,6) = 2 squares

[image: Second example]

---

The desired behavior for diagonals is that from given origin (4,4) to position (0,0) it results in 4 **not 8**.

[image: Desired behavior]

So, my main question is how could I calculate the distance between two squares in any origin to any desired position(within the presented range), but in such way that also works for diagonals, not only for X and Y axes.

Comment: Something useful could be $\max\{|x_{1}-x_{2}|,|y_{1}-y_{2}|\}$

Comment: @coffeemath i don't think OP wants taxi metric from the example he gave, then it would have been $d((4,4),(0,0))=8$ and not $4$ as he wants

Comment: note it is not taxicab metric, i was going on the entries being distances from the 0 in the center. But OP wants something else.  In my opinion the OP should say more about what is meant by distance, and more examples.

Comment: Maybe Minkowski distance? $({\sum_{i=1}^n} |x_{i}-y_{i}|^p)^{1/p}$

Comment: OP, can you tell me what the distance from the red 8 at $(0,0)$ to any of the green 1’s should be? I don’t understand what notion of “distance” you’re looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you want the maximum of the vertical and horizontal distances.

Comment: @Joe, the formula should calculate only straight lines, so I don't expect it to work with (0,0) to (5,4) for example.

Comment: @YagoBiermann: but any two points can be connected by a straight line. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I added more details, thanks in advance!

Comment: Finally I found what I needed, what I was looking for is the [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance). Thanks for everyone who engaged in the post!